# SQL - distinct case-insensitive collation query - retrieve lower case row instead of first

Tags: sql, distinct, collation

Using a distinct query with a case-insensitive collation like `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` will retrieve the first occurrence of any case-insensitive rows.

But I want to retrieve the lower case if both cases are present.

*If only one case is present in the data I want to retrieve that case. (unique occurrences of capital case should remain in capital case in the result set)*

**Table:**

```
id | col1  
----------
1 | Ab  
2 | ab  
3 | cd  
4 | Cd  
5 | Ef
```

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [col1] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
FROM dbo.table
```

Will retrieve: `Ab, cd, Ef`

**But I want to retrieve:** `ab, cd, Ef`

**Are there collation that can give me my desired results?**

Give priority to lower case instead of first case.

If not I have to use subselects.

1. Select all distinct values using case-sensitive collation (strangely is automatically sorted, almost the use case I wanted!)
2. Select from 1 using case-insensitive collation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be something like this

```
select
    min(T.col1 collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)
from dbo.Table as T
group by T.col1 collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: Hey, dont worry. This question was at work and i wasnt on so since then, and I wasn't 100% sure if there could be any drawbacks from the min function. Have to recheck it the next days at work. Then i will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
WITH cte As
(
   SELECT
      ID,
      Col1,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER
      (
         PARTITION BY
            Col1 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
         ORDER BY
             Col1 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS DESC,
             ID
      ) As RowNumber
   FROM
      dbo.Table
)
SELECT
   ID,
   Col1
FROM
   cte
WHERE
   RowNumber = 1
;
```

Comment: If I remove the DESC it works for one column. Looks pretty complex for such a task though. My idea with the subquery with two times usage of collation is not working, sql forbids two times collate (maybe using a view). But when I want to distinct on multiple columns adding a second column to the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` its not working.